# Copy Loop from 1 Sheet to Multiple Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops, optimization

I am able to achieve my results, but wanted to optimize my code further. Currently, for 15 projects, it takes 25 seconds. But I am expecting projects to be increased to 2000 which would take 30 minutes to execute this code. How can I further optimize this code.

Project_and_capex_costs = This sheet holds project details in each row
DC_Price_calc = This is where data is copied from above sheet and also Goal seek calculation is performed
DC_Price_table = This is where project data is copied from 1st sheet and also Goal seek is copied from DC_price_calc sheet
Revenue_forecast_table = This sheet data is copied from DC_Price_calc
Interest_forecast_table = This sheet data is copied from DC_Price_calc

The entire process above is repeated for each Project line by line

```
Sub Process_Price_Revenue()

Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long: n = 5
Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsCalcAndOutput As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet 'specify each type
Dim LR As Long

With Worksheets("Project_and_capex_costs")
   LR = .Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   For i = 10 To LR
        If .Cells(i, 5) <> "" Then
            Range(.Cells(i, "E"), Cells(i, "E")).Copy 'Project ID
            Worksheets("DC_price_calc").Cells(8, "B").PasteSpecial xlValues
            Range(.Cells(i, "F"), Cells(i, "F")).Copy 'Project Name
            Worksheets("DC_price_calc").Cells(9, "B").PasteSpecial xlValues
            Range(.Cells(i, "BL"), Cells(i, "BL")).Copy 'Funding Area
            Worksheets("DC_price_calc").Cells(16, "A").PasteSpecial xlValues
            Range(.Cells(i, "Q"), Cells(i, "Q")).Copy 'Capacity
            Worksheets("DC_price_calc").Cells(16, "B").PasteSpecial xlValues
            Range(.Cells(i, "DV"), Cells(i, "DV")).Copy 'LTP Calc Flag
            Worksheets("DC_price_calc").Cells(7, "D").PasteSpecial xlValues
            Range(.Cells(i, "BP"), Cells(i, "DC")).Copy 'CAPEX Costs
            Worksheets("DC_price_calc").Cells(20, "D").PasteSpecial xlValues
                    
            GoalSeekV1
            
            Range(.Cells(i, "E"), Cells(i, "E")).Copy 'Project ID
            Worksheets("DC_Price_table").Cells(n, "A").PasteSpecial xlValues
            Range(.Cells(i, "F"), Cells(i, "F")).Copy 'Project Name
            Worksheets("DC_Price_table").Cells(n, "B").PasteSpecial xlValues
            Range(.Cells(i, "BL"), Cells(i, "BL")).Copy 'Funding Area
            Worksheets("DC_Price_table").Cells(n, "C").PasteSpecial xlValues
            Range(.Cells(i, "Q"), Cells(i, "Q")).Copy 'Capacity
            Worksheets("DC_Price_table").Cells(n, "D").PasteSpecial xlValues
            Range(.Cells(i, "DV"), Cells(i, "DV")).Copy 'LTP Calc Flag
            Worksheets("DC_Price_table").Cells(n, "E").PasteSpecial xlValues
            Range("DC_Price").Copy
            Worksheets("DC_Price_table").Cells(n, "F").PasteSpecial xlValues
            
            Range(.Cells(i, "E"), Cells(i, "E")).Copy 'Project ID
            Worksheets("Revenue_forecast_table").Cells(n, "A").PasteSpecial xlValues
            Range(.Cells(i, "F"), Cells(i, "F")).Copy 'Project Name
            Worksheets("Revenue_forecast_table").Cells(n, "B").PasteSpecial xlValues
            Range(.Cells(i, "BL"), Cells(i, "BL")).Copy 'Funding Area
            Worksheets("Revenue_forecast_table").Cells(n, "C").PasteSpecial xlValues
            Range(.Cells(i, "Q"), Cells(i, "Q")).Copy 'Capacity
            Worksheets("Revenue_forecast_table").Cells(n, "D").PasteSpecial xlValues
            Range("DC_revenue_forecast").Copy 'DC Revenue Forecast
            Worksheets("Revenue_forecast_table").Cells(n, "E").PasteSpecial xlValues
            
            Range(.Cells(i, "E"), Cells(i, "E")).Copy 'Project ID
            Worksheets("Interest_forecast_table").Cells(n, "A").PasteSpecial xlValues
            Range(.Cells(i, "F"), Cells(i, "F")).Copy 'Project Name
            Worksheets("Interest_forecast_table").Cells(n, "B").PasteSpecial xlValues
            Range(.Cells(i, "BL"), Cells(i, "BL")).Copy 'Funding Area
            Worksheets("Interest_forecast_table").Cells(n, "C").PasteSpecial xlValues
            Range(.Cells(i, "Q"), Cells(i, "Q")).Copy 'Capacity
            Worksheets("Interest_forecast_table").Cells(n, "D").PasteSpecial xlValues
            Range("Interest_cost_forecast").Copy 'Interest Cost Forecast
            Worksheets("Interest_forecast_table").Cells(n, "E").PasteSpecial xlValues
            
            
            n = n + 1 'update so that we don't overwrite next time
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub


Sub GoalSeekV1()

    Dim rngStartGoal As Range
    Set rngStartGoal = Range("DC_price_calc!$AQ$31")
    
    Dim rngStartInput As Range
    Set rngStartInput = Range("DC_Price")
    
    rngStartGoal.GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=rngStartInput
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Whats the % time taken for goal seek to compute?

Comment: The Goal Seek calculation is dependent on the Copy from the 1st sheet. So I have to do copy first and then Goal Seek. So cannot comment specifically how much time Goal seek is taking

Comment: You can use `Timer` to find out what % of each iteration is taken by Goal Seek (perform a few runs with and without `GoalSeekV1` commented out) - that will tell you how much scope you have for speeding this up.

Comment: Yes, similar to what @TimWilliams suggested, you can also declare some variables to accumulate the time goal seek take, basically pausing the timer when not goal seeking, and continue timer when goal seeking. Then compute the average %.

Comment: Another possible solution is turn off calculation when not gaol seeking but only copy paste which may slow down the procedure, `application.calculation = vbManual`.

Comment: Also, `destinationsheet.destinationcell.value = sourcesheet.sourcecell.value` should be quicker than Copy/Paste Special Values.

Comment: Thanks Rosetta, I added these 2 lines and it massively reduced the total time for 1000 projects from 75 mins to 8 mins Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Comment: You could eliminate a lot of those 8 minutes by avoiding the clipboard, e.g. your first copy/paste could be consolidated thus `Worksheets("DC_price_calc").Cells(8, "B").Value2 = .Cells(i, "E").Value2` - you'll be surprised at the difference it will make if you do this for all your copy/paste lines

Comment: How about this line how can I use .Value for this line? Range(.Cells(i, "BP"), Cells(i, "DC")).Copy 'CAPEX Costs
 Worksheets("DC_price_calc").Cells(20, "D").PasteSpecial xlValues

Comment: I tried adding Range(.Cells(i, "BP"), Cells(i, "DC")).Value2 but then it seems my logic not working correctly. I have Goal Seek calculation after this step. I want for every row that I read for other sheet I copy in the DC_price_calc sheet which has some calculations which then performs Goal seek on that calculation. If I use .Value2 I do not get the right results.